# Localization of a DotNetNuke website

Tags: vb.net, localization, dotnetnuke

I am working on a website in dnn. I want to change the language of website or particular page. So I download the language package for spanish(es-es),chinese(zh-cn) and install them from host. Next when I changed the language of browser then the website language didn't change. Working on dnn 5.0.

Please let me know how I can use language packages in dnn website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably ask this in the DotNetNuke forums: http://www.dotnetnuke.com/tabid/795/default.aspx.

There's one dedicated forum for questions about language packs and localization. You will probably find your answer there: http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Community/Forums/tabid/795/forumid/77/scope/threads/Default.aspx

Answer (score 1):

For initial translations and maintenance of DotNetNuke translations, I recommend the use of OmegaT. It handles resx files directly. And content (such as HTML or Blogs) can be downloaded, translated and then uploaded thanks to the APIs of DNN (drop me a note if you need the scripts).

OmegaT stores the translations in it's memory (a TMX file, which is actually some kind of XML). It also uses Google Translate and similars, and has a fast user interface which increases translation speed a lot when compared against continously waiting for DotNetNuke to handle your updated resources.

More info on [OmegaT](http://www.omegat.org). An example of a translated site and modules: [site translated from Dutch into English](http://www.invantive.com)

Answer (score 0):

The language packs don't always have translations for everything on the site, especially content that you added yourself.  You'll need to do two things to get them working properly:

1. Go to Admin > Languages, and enable the languages you want to use.
2. Open the Language Editor and start translating.  Under each resource name, you will see an edit text box for the localized value, and a read-only text box for the default value.  In most cases, you'll need to translate verbatim what you see under "default value".

Comment: Thanks for reply. But My question was that how can we change the language of website, After adding package I got the images on header with language's indication. But these changes only menu item not the information. 
Do you know How can we change all page information.

Comment: Right.  I downloaded the Spanish language pack, and had this same experience.  The language packs, by default only translate the core content in the base DNN Portal, which is pretty much limited to the menu navigation.  The webmaster is responsible for translating everything else.

Comment: The benefit of them is that they contain the logic to switch back and forth between languages you have setup, and I believe can auto-detect which language to use based on the user's regional/browser settings.

Comment: @Deepak language packages do not translate content, only the core.

Answer (score 0):

We had to write our own menu provider to get the menu to do this - instead of going for the resource files we went for a database solution - other reasons applied to this as well - we also built an interface for doing this - as for things like the text/html module there are some third party builds that allow you to nationalize content. Apollo comes to mind [Apollo Software](http://www.apollo-software.nl/) they have some multilanguage modules

Comment: For reference, "Apollo Software" no longer exist.

Answer (score 0):

The language packs will typically only localize text used by the core such as "Login" and "Settings". It is designed so that you can have a site in a language other than English, not so you can have multiple languages on one site. You can easily have multiple portals, each with a different language.

In order to have multiple locales on one portal you will need to use a third party module or develop your own.